# Шаблон в очереди проверок на английском

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Проверял ответ пользователя в теме [Задача Minimum of two. Проблема с циклом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766878/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-minimum-of-two-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/768499?noredirect=1#comment1197513_768499), выбрал стандартное действие `Это комментарий типа «Спасибо»`, которое добавляет комментарий `“Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете проголосовать за вопросы и ответы, которые сочтёте полезными.”`, в итоге комментарий добавился на английском:

> [image: Английский текст из очереди проверок]

Сейчас повторить подобное уже не могу :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чате уже [уведомили](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42182517#42182517) об этом. Что-то изменилось в исходной (английской) строке и перевод «поехал». Я утвердил новый (старый) перевод. После подгрузки базы (как Николас дёрнет) и пересборки сайта (как дёрнет разработчик) должно подхватиться.